# Should update redux state onchange events?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm having that question on mind. It's right to update redux state on handleChange event? I mean, i guess that working with hooks to have like an intermediate state and only update the redux state when i'm skipping that component could be a better practice.

This is my code, a very simple example.

```
const handleTitle(event= => {
    setCursoTitle(event.target.value);
}
```

And this is how it should be to avoid updates  on every onChange event.

```
const [cursoTitle, setcursoTitle] = useState('');
```

```
const handleTitle = (event) => {
      //handle onChange from Text Field
        setCursoTitle(event.target.value);


    } 
const exitForm = () => {
    //update Redux State
    setCursoTitle(cursoTitle);
}
```

It's very expensive to update the redux state on every on change event? What way do you think is better ?

Comment: Single store keeping your global state updated *exclusively* through dispatching actions to app reducer is recommended pattern. To bind your global state updates to `onChange` prop, you may use `mapDispatchToProps` just the way it is done in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59307493/11299053).

Comment: Ok, i've found one thing that it's interesting on that post. "onChnage values should be stored in local state and not in redux state. Only global values should be stored in redux state ideally." So, keeping the value on a local store, a hook, and when its "consolidates" put it on a redux state, seems kinda fine with that aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends of the scenario.Per example, if you are using websocket, i dont think your solution will work properly.

Take a look at https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce. It's a way to update your redux state only when the user stop typing. This way, your redux really represent your current data and you don't re-render your component on every key down.

Comment: thanks, it's okey, im only passing data to the server when data is "consolidated". Assuming that,  i guess that i'm gonna set my redux state onFocusOut.

Comment: onBlur is more supported than onFocusOut. I invite you to check the minor differences between them.

Comment: onBlur={focusOut} yeah i know.  I use the intermedian state with hooks and i update my state onBlur. I like that approach instead of the approach used by use-debounce, cos i don't need to install nothing, and it's working fine. But i'm still wonder, i guess that only update the state once it's better than updating the state every onChange event is trigger...

Comment: This is exactly the point of using a debounce. Instead of updating your state on every key down. You update it once the user stop typing. But to answer your question, yes it is better to update your state once than on every key down. But it could depend of the scenario..